# Explanation of Cost Calculation for DTU based Azure SQL

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Can someone explain to me how the cost calculation for the DTU-based Azure SQL model works?

Don't get me wrong. I am not looking for an explanation of the DTU model. I understand that a DTU is a blended measure of CPU, memory and IO resources, etc.
But what I can't find with certainty is the information on how exactly this is calculated.

For example, if I use the model with 20 DTUs, it says the following:

[image]

Do you basically pay 27.56€ per month, no matter how much you end up using the database? But why does it say "estimated cost / month"?

For example, if I run intensive operations on the database for 3 hours every day, which pushes the 20 DTUs to their limit (I don't care about throttling), but I don't do anything else with the database, will I also be charged 27.56€ per month or does it somehow depend on the hours used?

Because that's what it shows me in the pricing calculator:

[image]

Do I understand correctly that only every active hour is charged? So in the example above, would I pay approximately 30 (days) x 3 hours x 0.0403$/hour = 3.63$ per month?

Comment: I believe you purchase capacity, whether you use it or not. As long as the database is online (even if it's doing nothing), you will be charged for it. So even if you only run it hard for 3 hours a day, but it's 'on' 24 hours a day, you will be charged the full cost for 24 hours each day.

Comment: But why does it say "estimated cost". And why can you calculate by hours in the pricing calculator? And why does it say "If the SQL database is active for less than one hour, you are billed for each hour the database exists [...]"?

Comment: The wording there is admittedly poor. In the DTU model you are charged for every hour that the DTUs are allocated to you, whether you use them or not does not impact the price you pay. All of these price calculators, in the portal and the official calculator, will say that the cost is estimated because final cost depends on storage, bandwidth, etc, and the exact amount of time that the allocation is for. If you want to pay for only the time that the database is actively in use you should see if the serverless model will work for you.

Comment: They also estimate a month's cost as 730 hours. That's only an average. In actuality, months with 31 days (744 hours) are more expensive than months with 30 days (720 hours). Re 'billed for a whole hour, even if the database is active for less than an hour' - as @KonTheCat indicates, in the serverless model you can pause the database. You could also (I guess) delete the database and recreate it as needed. But if you recreate at 3:50, you'll still get charged for the 3:00-4:00 hour. See https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/stop-azure-sql-database/ba-p/3890369.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your questions

> Do you basically pay 27.56€ per month, no matter how much you end up
> using the database?

**Yes, in DTU model you are going to pay 27.56 per month, no matter how much you end up using the database**

> But why does it say "estimated cost / month"?

**Estimated cost is often used to indicate that the calculated cost is an approximation and may vary based on different factors.**

> Do I understand correctly that only every active hour is charged? So in the example above, would I pay approximately 30 (days) x 3 hours x 0.0403$/hour = 3.63$ per month?

**In Azure SQL Database case it's billed by hours of existence and not by usage.
For example, if a database exists for 12 hours in a month, your bill will show usage of 0.5 days.
You are billed for each hour a database exists using the highest service tier + performance level that applied during that hour, regardless of usage or whether the database was active for less than an hour. For example, if you create a single database and delete it 5 minutes later your bill will reflect a charge for 1 database hour.**

If you are looking to be charged by the hour of usage, then you should consider [Azure SQL Database Servless](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/serverless-tier-overview?view=azuresql-db&tabs=general-purpose).

[Serverless is a compute tier for single databases in Azure SQL Database that automatically pauses databases during inactive periods when only storage is billed and automatically resumes databases when activity returns.
If auto-pausing is enabled, but a database does not auto-pause after the delay period, the application or user sessions may be preventing auto-pausing](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/stop-azure-sql-database/ba-p/3890369)

Comment: _estimated cost / month_ is because it is billed by the hour and different months have different hours. The estimate is made from the number of hours in a year divided by 12.

Answer (score 0):

You asked "Do you basically pay 27.56€ per month, no matter how much you end up using the database?" You don't pay that fixed amount, that is an estimate that does not include the storage costs of LTR Backups depending of the retention period for those backups and it does not include the [egress traffic](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/bandwidth/) from the Azure SQL Database that is hidden on the Azure invoice as egress traffic for all the Azure products you are using, and you don't have a way to know how much you are paying for egress traffic from Azure SQL only.

With Azure SQL you pay hourly by reserved capacity, and it does not matter if you use that capacity or not. With Azure SQL Serverless you pay by the minute, and you can configure auto-pause when the database is not in use after a period of time, but you will still pay for storage resources consumed even when a database is auto-paused.

To save money, try to schedule a scale down of the database during known periods of time of low usage, like weekends, after business hours, holidays, etc. You can consider using Azure SQL Serverless also.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can I schedule a scale down of the database?

Comment: You can schedule to execute the following command from Azure Automation: $sqlCommand.CommandText= "ALTER DATABASE [YourDatabase] MODIFY (EDITION = 'Premium', MAXSIZE = 512 GB, SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = 'P2');"